# Using optim within boot with R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, statistics-bootstrap

I'm wanting to compute the standard errors of parameters estimated through `optim` via bootstrapping. The aim is to bootstrap the data used as the input for the `optim` function.

The initial optim function is given as

```
f = function (theta) {

A = rbind (c(1,theta[1], theta[2]), c(theta[3],1,theta[4]), c(theta[5],theta[6],1))
S1 = diag ( c(theta[7],theta[8],theta[9]) )
S2 = diag ( c(theta[10],theta[11],theta[12]) )
S3 = diag ( c(theta[13],theta[14],theta[15]) )
S4 = diag ( c(theta[16],theta[17],theta[18]) )  

M1 <-   A %*% C1 %*% t(A) - S1 
M2 <-   A %*% C2 %*% t(A) - S2 
M3 <-   A %*% C3 %*% t(A) - S3 
M4 <-   A %*% C4 %*% t(A) - S4 

mm =  sum(as.vector(M1)*(T1/T), as.vector(M2)*(T2/T),
     as.vector(M3)*(T3/T), as.vector(M4)*(T4/T))^2
 return (mm)     
}
result = optim (rep(0,18), fn=f)
```

Where C1 etc is a covariance matrix i wish to create via bootstrapping. The code for bootstrapping using `boot` is given below.

```
bootresid=cbindX(steady.resid,dairy.resid,nzdusd.resid,interest.resid)

bootfun = function(bootresid, i) {

C1 = cov(bootresid[i,1:3],use = "na.or.complete")
C2 = cov(bootresid[i,4:6],use = "na.or.complete")
C3 = cov(bootresid[i,7:9],use = "na.or.complete")
C4 = cov(bootresid[i,10:12],use = "na.or.complete")

ans = optim (rep(0,18), fn = f)
return(ans$par)
}

bootres = boot(bootresid, statistic = bootfun, 500)
```

This returns an error of unused arguments within the `optim` function. Is it possible to use `optim` within the boot function? Do i need to make changes to the way the `optim` function is defined?

EDIT: As Vincent suggested, additional arguments must be passed through the initial function. Importantly for this problem, an additional indices must be given to ensure `optim` is repeated with different data. The final solution is.

```
bootfun = function(bootresid, i, d, C1, C2, C3, C4) {

C1 = cov(bootresid[i,1:3],use = "na.or.complete")
C2 = cov(bootresid[i,4:6],use = "na.or.complete")
C3 = cov(bootresid[i,7:9],use = "na.or.complete")
C4 = cov(bootresid[i,10:12],use = "na.or.complete")

ans = optim (rep(0,18), fn=f)

return(ans$par [d])
}

bootres = boot(bootresid, statistic = bootfun, 500)
```

Comment: `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, `C4` should be passed as arguments -- otherwise, `f` will look for them in the environment in which it was defined, i.e., the top-level environment, not the body of the `bootfun` function.

Comment: Thanks @Vincent. This and including another argument for repeating the `optim` function has given the desired result.